# Django: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' error

Tags: python, regex, django, attributes, regex-group

I want correct code of this

```
try:
        res = self.browser.open('https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1',form_data)
        response = res.read()
        self.fbid = re.search('https://www.facebook.com/(.*)\?sk=info',response)
        self.fbid = re.search('https://www.facebook.com/(.*)',self.fbid.group(1))
        self.fbid = re.search('https://www.facebook.com/(.*)',self.fbid.group(1))
    except urllib2.HTTPError,e :
        print "****exception****inside login  error code: %s" % (e.code)
    res.close()
except urllib2.HTTPError,e :
     print "****exception****inside login  error code: %s" % (e.code)

#print " server Response Code: %s " % (res.code)
```

I got this error

```
File "facebotv2.py", line 122, in login
self.fbid = re.search('https://www.facebook.com/(.*)',self.fbid.group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

the full code here : https://github.com/pun1sh3r/facebot/blob/master/facebotv2.py

Comment: Perhaps you should check each of your regexes actually returns something before stuffing it into the next regex. It would seem one of them is returning `None`

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that your `response` doesn't matches your regex `'https://www.facebook.com/(.*)\?sk=info'` that's why it is not capturing any group

Always check whether your re.search returns an object or not

```
if self.fbid:
      self.fbid = re.search('https://www.facebook.com/(.*)',self.fbid.group(1))
else:
    """do something else"""
```

if your regex matches something it'll probably display something like `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7166410>` which would make your if condition true and you can extract the groups from that match using grouping